# Recursion - Implementation of an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to understand this algorithm used for finding `Permutations of a String`

If you’re past the last position

```
- Print the string
- Return
```

Otherwise

```
- For each letter in the input string
- If it’s marked as used, skip to the next letter
- Else place the letter in the current position
- Mark the letter as used
- Permute remaining letters starting at current position + 1
- Mark the letter as unused
```

*Here’s a Java implementation of this algorithm:*

```
public class Permutations {
   private boolean[] used;
   private StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
   private final String in;

   public Permutations( final String str ){
     in = str;
     used = new boolean[ in.length() ];
  }

  public void permute( ){
     if( out.length() == in.length() ){
     System.out.println( out );
     return;
 }
     for( int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i ){
       if( used[i] ) continue;   ------------------- // This line
       out.append( in.charAt(i) );
       used[i] = true;
       permute();
       used[i] = false;
       out.setLength( out.length() - 1 );
      }
   }
}
```

I can understand the other parts of the code except the line commented as `This line`. How is it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the purpose of the line you highlighted is,
Code is checking whether character at position ' i ' is already used or not.If it is already used then [continue](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=279)(i.e. directly go to next iteration in for-loop).

it is equivalent to

```
for( int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i ){
      if(!used[i] ) {
          out.append( in.charAt(i) );
          used[i] = true;
          permute();
          used[i] = false;
          out.setLength( out.length() - 1 );
      }
}
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: @MavenMaverick accept any of the answer, so it helps others who look for same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how `continue` is working:

From [The continue Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop.

In your program you are initializing `used = new boolean[ in.length() ];` so by default all the value in this array will be false.

From  `if( used[i] ) continue;` If current value for `used[i]` is `ture` means already processed then it will skip current iteration and continue with next.

Answer (score 0):

continue will skip current loop body and iterate from starting point in loop and check again condition to enter the loop again.
in your code

```
for( int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i ){
   if( used[i] ) continue;   ------------------- // This line
   out.append( in.charAt(i) );
   used[i] = true;
   permute();
   used[i] = false;
   out.setLength( out.length() - 1 );
  }
```

if `used[i] == true` then all the line below to continue statement will not execute for current iteration. control will go to condition statement in loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

It just skipping execution of the statements under if block and continuing iteration with next i value.

Comment: @AJ. The answer is fully correct and actually answers the question, albeit formulated a little problematic.